# java :discovering locale from datetimezone

Tags: java, datetime, locale

on the machines my code runs on the locale information is not correctly configured , but the `dateTimeZone` is correctly configured.
Since there is a many to one relationship between locale and timezone it should theoretically be possible to convert the timezone to locale

I am looking for a function `getLocaleFromDateTimeZone` that can be used like this:

```
DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin");
Locale loca = getLocaleFromDateTimeZone(dtz) // should return Locale.GERMAN
```

Comment: There is a many-to-many relationship between locale and timezone.

Comment: And what will tell you whether the current time zone is "regular" as opposed to "daylight saving"?

Comment: `DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin")` is same as `DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Paris")` or `DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Madrid)`. Should your function return GERMAN, FRENCH or SPANISH ?

Comment: i would like "Europe/Berlin" to return GERMAN  and "Europe/Paris" to return FRENCH . it might be that two countries sharing the the same hours in their timezone might have different definitions regarding first day of the week etc ..

Comment: Robby , is there an example that you can give where one timezone serves more then one locale?